# Partition/install issues

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation, multi-boot

I am new to Ubuntu and tried to install 10.1 as dual boot option from a USB. At first I encountered the error when in partition dialogue of installation process that cannot find root directory. I did a search on Ubuntu forums and did this as in one of the posts.

> Make sure that the partition file system you wish to install Linux, Ubuntu or Backtrack on it is ext4, ext3 or ext2, and not FAT32 or NTFS.
>
> Then mount `/` on it:
>
> During the installation process press "change" on the partition you wish to use
>
> Make sure "do not use this partition" scroll is not chosen, scroll to `ext4`, `ext3` or `ext2`
>
> On the "mount" field write `/`
>
> Click ok, then next a message will appear saying something like "swap area was not defined, do you wish to continue or choose a swap area?", click "ok" and continue or click "go back" and choose another partition and click change, on the file system scroll choose "swap" and click "ok" and next

All good but when I rebooted I could not find Windows  vista as in dual boot option. Plus I could not see wireless networks and in the process of trying to find out what went wrong the soft switch somehow turned off and as I cannot boot in Windows  I have no idea what to do.

Again searching internet I found a post which said the dual boot problem can be overcome by installing gparted but when I tried I got the message

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information.. Done E: Couldn't find package gparted

I thought I am going to copy my stuff from my hard disk and try to install Windows  but I found out that I have two partitions which are different from what I had before installing Ubuntu. I now have filesystem partition1 119 GB ext4, swap partition 5 1.1 GB swap and extended partition 2 1.1 GB. And I cannot mount 119 GB where all my personal videos, photos are if still there.

Now I cannot boot from Windows  even. Need help on what to do? Best case scenario would be to be able to copy my stuff before I mess up the system further. Else a dual boot system and if not then how do I install vista again. I have Windows  CD.

Cheers guys and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All drives must be shown when you are on Ubuntu. Just to double check, you could try to start Ubuntu from a Live-CD. Upon logging in, you must be able to view all your drives. And if you have managed to keep your Windows drive safe, you can copy your stuff to an external storage media. 
Again to clarify, if your Windows partition is safe, you would not need to re-install Windows.